# Working Setup for Gulp, Connect, AngularUI Router and HTML5 Mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-router, gulp

I've tried and search a lot but I could not find any working solution for the following setup:

- gulp
- connect (https://github.com/senchalabs/connect)
- connect-live-reload
- angularJS
- angularUI router with HTML5 mode on

The last option I tried was with connect-modrewrite, but that also didn't work. I think I got close by using https://github.com/expressjs/urlrouter but although it says, that is supports the express server functions, the setup descriped at angularUI router FAQ (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) doesn't work

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
   // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
   res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

I get the error, that send file doesn't work. I abandoned this way as I saw that the urlrouter project seams to be abandoned. So I tried to use connect-modrewrite and have this configuration now:

```
gulp.task('connect', ['sass', 'fonts'], function () {
    var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
    var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
    var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');
    var app = require('connect')()
        .use(require('connect-livereload')({port: 35729}))
        .use(serveStatic('.tmp'))
        .use(serveStatic('app'))
        .use('/bower_components', serveStatic('bower_components'))
        .use(serveIndex('app'))
        .use(modRewrite(['^ app/index.html  [L]']));

    require('http').createServer(app)
        .listen(9010)
        .on('listening', function () {
            console.log('Started connect web server on http://localhost:9010');
        });
});

gulp.task('serve', ['connect', 'watch'], function () {
    require('opn')('http://localhost:9010');
});
```

But what I get is just a "Cannot GET" when trying to load a page from a link directly. So what have I missed? How can I get the HTML5 mode working with connect or do I really have to use expressJS?